# VS Code Test Explorer can't find tests

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, test-explorer

We must test a new feature before pushing it to production. For some reason we can't access our tests with Visual Studio Code (it must be VS Code).

I found this thread (which didn't help me) [NXunit Test Explorer isn't showing tests on VS Code (Test Explorer UI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185509/nxunit-test-explorer-isnt-showing-tests-on-vs-code-test-explorer-ui)

[image]

A few important details:

1. I'm using SSH feature to run the code on an Ubuntu 16 [image]
2. Full path of the folder which contains the correct .sln:  `/home/XXX/repos/YYY/Automation/CrossAutomation`
3. Full path of the tests project .csproj: `/home/XXX/repos/YYY/Automation/CrossAutomation/CrossPlatform.Tests/CrossPlatform.Tests.csproj`
4. When I specify the full path of `Tests.csproj` is `settings.json` I get the same result
5. using the command dotnet sln  add <.CSPROJ PATH>  didn't help.
6. No errors when building the solution.
7. Here are my extensions

   [image]
8. Sometimes it shows 0 and sometimes 311 (which is the correct number)

   [image]
9. Everything worked normal yesterday (can't tell what changed).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.